# Emacs: mouse doesn't work when more than 2 panes across are open

Tags: emacs

I have a strange situation going on. I have the following code in my `init.el` to enable mouse support:

```
(unless window-system
  (require 'mouse)
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1)))
  (defun track-mouse (e))
  (setq mouse-sel-mode t)
)
```

The mouse seems to work fine when I have two panes or fewer across (any number of panes up-down seems to be ok) open in emacs, and furthermore works fine *in the first two panes* (left-to-write) if I have more. However, it starts getting weird in the other panes after the first two. When I click in those panes, sometimes it moves the cursor as I thought, and sometimes it does nothing except say

```
M-[ m is undefined
```

in the minibuffer. Does anyone know what's going on? I'm using emacs in terminal mode, by the way, and running it through an `emacsclient` attached to `emacs --daemon`.

Comment: Can you test with a single pane that is over 220ish characters wide, say maybe 300 characters.  Then try clicking near the end of the line and see if the mouse behaves as you expect?  IIRC there is some bug/limit on terminals with mouse support regarding cells past something in the 220s and I'm curious if that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Oh, yeah the same thing happened. That must be it. Is there a fix?

Comment: What terminal are you using? Also, are you using a multiplexer like screen or tmux? More info can be found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/485956/clicking-far-away-in-vim-in-tmux-in-urxvt).

Comment: The xterm-mouse-mode code has seen a fair bit of changes lately (IIRC both before 24.5 and after 24.5).  So I suggest you try 24.5 and/or Emacs's development branch (to become 25.1).